# IntelliJ can't find packages in test directory

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to get into Java ecosystem and I'm building a simple AWS Lambda handler. I have a project set up in IntelliJ using Gradle build system and I have problems with unit tests.

First, the project structure:

```
➜  Gradle tree -L 2
.
├── build
│   ├── classes
│   ├── generated
│   ├── reports
│   ├── test-results
│   └── tmp
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── settings.gradle
└── src
    ├── main
    └── test
```

And the `src` details:

```
➜  src tree
.
├── main
│   ├── java
│   │   └── main
│   │       ├── Lambda.java
│   │       └── Logger.java
│   └── resources
└── test
    ├── java
    │   └── main
    │       └── LambdaTest.java
    └── resources
```

The `Lambda.java` code:

```java
package main;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;



public class Lambda implements RequestHandler<Object, String> {
    private final Logger logger;

    public Lambda(){
        logger = new Logger();
    }

    public String getGreetings() {
        return "Hello, world!";
    }

    public String getJson() {
        String json = "{\"message\": \"" + getGreetings() + "\"}";
        logger.log(json);
        return json;
    }

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Object event, Context context) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        logger.log(String.valueOf(event));
        Message m = gson.fromJson(getJson(), Message.class);
        return gson.toJson(m);
    }
}
```

And the test code is:

```java
package main;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;


public class LambdaTest {
    @Test
    public void testLambdaGreetings() {
        Lambda l = new Lambda();
        Assertions.assertEquals("Hello, world!", l.getGreetings());
    }
}
```

`settings.gradle` file:

```
rootProject.name = 'Gradle'
include('main')
```

I can run this test and make it succeed and fail when I want (eg. when I change the expected message to "Hello", it fails as predicted). It works fine both when I run it from the command line, ie. `./gradlew test` and from IntelliJ's interface.

[image: Test succeeded in interface]

The `java` folder under `main` is marked as sources root and `java` in `test` directory is marked as "Test sources root". It seems fine, but IntelliJ in the test folder does not see the resources from `src/main`.

[image: Cannot resolve symbol Lambda]

The question is: how can I configure IntelliJ to recognize symbols in the sources root?

Comment: Is it possible to share project example?

Comment: @y.bedrov I've pushed the project to github: https://github.com/gonczor/Gradle

Comment: Works fine on my side. What IDE version do you use? Please try to run "File | Invalidate Caches".

Comment: Community, version 2020.3 installej as Ubuntu snap package.

Invalidating cached did not help

Comment: I changed one line in `settings.gradle` to `rootProject.name = 'src'` and after invalidating cache again it works. I've added new package, new class and I'm able to test it. Could this be the cause?

Comment: That's strange. It's only project name. Could you please try to revert it back to "Gradle"?

Comment: It's still correct after changing the name and invalidating cache.

Comment: Seems there was some issue with Gradle import and reimport (after changing name) helped.